# How do you pass a variant dim to a string when concatenating?

Tags: excel, vba, string, concatenation, variant

I'm trying to export a file with a specific name (where different parts of the name are variables). So far, the first two strings are not causing issues. The problem arises when I perform the index match function and get a variant data type value. I'm unable to convert the variant type to string to use later on in the code. Snippet below:

```
Sub Export_Imgs()

    Dim tempSht as Range
    Dim dataSht as Range
    Dim matCell as Range
    Dim jobNum as Range
    Dim buildDate As String
    Dim buildID As String
    Dim imgFile As String
    Dim matID As Variant
    Dim imgMap As String
    Dim imgPDF As String
    Dim imgJPG As String

    Set tempSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Template")
    Set dataSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Machines & Material")
    Set matCell = tempSht.Range("$E$81")
    Set jobNum = tempSht.Range("$E$12")

    'Define file name variables
    buildDate = Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    buildID = Left(jobNum, InStr(jobNum, ".") - 1)
    matID = WorksheetFunction.Index((dataSht.ListObjects("AMmat").ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange), _
        WorksheetFunction.Match(matCell, dataSht.ListObjects("AMmat").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0))

        imgMap = "C:\Users\Example\Desktop\"
        imgJPG = buildDate & "_" & buildID & "_" & CStr(matID) & ".jpg"
        imgFile = imgMap & imgJPG

End Sub
```

I get a "type mismatch" error on the imgJPG line towards the bottom of the code. I feel as if I'm missing something quite simple. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Index` here, but instead something like the following approach:

```
With dataSht.ListObjects("AMmat")
    Dim rw
    rw = Application.Match(matCell.Value, .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)

    If Not IsError(rw) Then
        matId = .ListColumns(4).DataBodyRange.Cells(rw).Value
    End If   
End With
```

Comment: The above code did the trick. Still trying to understand why the index function would throw an error code however as this is essentially the same. Could you explain?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, but I think it's clearer to avoid `Index` (and `WorksheetFunction`s in general) and just use a `Range` approach.